# EJB injected in @Model bean gets created on every request (GlassFish)

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, ejb, cdi

i can not find a soultion or any reference to this on the web. here is the problem

I have a very simple web project

- index.xhtml

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
        <h:head>
            <title>Index</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <h:outputText value="#{myBean.message}" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.name}" />
                    <h:commandButton action="#{myBean.sayHello()}"
                                     value="Say Hello">
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

- MyBean.java

```
    import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;
    import javax.inject.Inject;

    @Model
    public class MyBean
    {
        @Inject 
        private MyEJB myEjb;

        public MyBean()
        {
            System.out.println("Creating MyBean");
        }

        private String name;

        private String message;

        public void sayHello()
        {
            setMessage(myEjb.sayHello(getName()));
        }

        public String getMessage()
        {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message)
        {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

- MyEJB.java

```
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;

    @Stateless
    public class MyEJB
    {

        public MyEJB()
        {
            System.out.println("Creating MyEJB");
        }

        public String sayHello(String name)
        {
            return "Hello " + name;
        }

    }
```

this work correctly but the glassfish log shows this

Información: Creating MyBean
Información: Creating MyBean
Información: Creating MyEJB
Información: Creating MyBean
Información: Creating MyEJB
Información: Creating MyEJB

on a single request.

that means tha MyBean was created 3 times on the request and MyEJB 3 times more

i wander if this is a normal behavior or it's a bug on glassfish or maybe im doing something really wrong here, becouse a seriuos application would have a problem if so many objects are created and destroyed on every request.

if i change to a more classical aproche like this

```
    import javax.ejb.EJB;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

    @RequestScoped
    @ManagedBean
    public class MyBean
    {
        @EJB
        private MyEJB myEjb;

        public MyBean()
        {
            System.out.println("Creating MyBean");
        }

        private String name;

        private String message;

        public void sayHello()
        {
            setMessage(myEjb.sayHello(getName()));
        }

        public String getMessage()
        {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message)
        {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

the output it´s diferent

i get 1 ejb created and then the rest of the request are handled by that instance
and MyBean is created once for every request.

please helpme maybe i have missuntherestod the cdi specification.

thanks

Comment: Ok sorry, first it does not create the beans 3 times, it was one per request, i was presing f5 on the browser, and i solve the EJB creation problem by adding @Named to it. but i did't see this requirement on any cdi tutorial i've read, so i'm confuse

Comment: Understand that there is nothing "classical" about your second code example.  The first one uses CDI for injection and the second one uses JSF & EJB for injection, two very different models.  @Model is a shortcut for the CDI versions of RequestScoped and Named.  So yes, your model object will get created multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging the constructor of a EJB / CDI / JSF / ... component is a false friend.

In modern frameworks there is **a lot of stuff going on behind the scenes** - quite a bit of it using Java reflection - and you cannot rely on a call to a constructor indicating that you have a  fresh and ready-to-use component.

What you have to do is using one of the appropriate lifecycle hooks. These are explicitly designed to be called after / before a component is created /  destroyed / de-passivated / passivated.

In your case, use `@PostConstruct`, [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html).